# Not able to retain the values in the row of dynamically formed table using javascript after page refresh

Tags: javascript, html, database, jsp, servlets

I have the following js code in my jsp. Im not able to retain those textbox values below after the page is refreshed. Any idea how to retain the values?
Im calling this js function onclick of a html button so that it dynamically adds the row to the table.

```
 <script>
        function addRow(tableID) {
            if(validateForm()==true){
            document.getElementById('cruisedowntime2').style.display = "block";
            var table = document.getElementById(tableID);

            var rowCount = table.rows.length;
            var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

          /*  var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
            var element1 = document.createElement("input");
            element1.type = "checkbox";
            element1.name = "chkbox[]";
            element1.defaultChecked="true";
            cell1.appendChild(element1);*/

            var cell0 = row.insertCell(0);
            var element0=document.createElement("select");
            element0.name="cruiselinedropdown";
            var dropdownlist1=document.getElementById("droplist1");

            var defaultselected=dropdownlist1.options[dropdownlist1.selectedIndex].value;
    //window.location.replace("http://localhost:8085/Bridge_Downtime_Utility/Servlet?var="+defaultselected);
            <%Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();
                                    for (int i = 0; i < crsenamelist.size(); i++) {
                                        map.put(crsenamelist.get(i),crsecodelist.get(i));
                                    }


                       %>
            element0.options.add( new Option(defaultselected,defaultselected,true,true) );

            element0.options.add( new Option("--","") );
            <%

      for(Map.Entry m:map.entrySet()){   %>
            element0.options.add( new Option("<%=m.getValue()%>","<%=m.getValue()%>") );

            cell0.appendChild(element0);<%}%>

            var textbox3=document.getElementById('starttime');
            var textbox7=document.getElementById('startdate');
            var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
            var element2 = document.createElement("input");
            element2.title="Date: YYYY-MM-DD";
            element2.type = "text";
            element2.name = "starttimetextbox";
            element2.value=textbox7.value+"  "+textbox3.value;
            cell2.appendChild(element2);

            var textbox5=document.getElementById('endtime');
            var textbox9=document.getElementById('enddate');
            var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
            var element3 = document.createElement("input");
            element3.title="Date: YYYY-MM-DD";
            element3.type = "text";
            element3.name = "endtimetextbox";
            element3.value=textbox9.value+"  "+textbox5.value;
            cell3.appendChild(element3);

            var textbox1=document.getElementById('descrip');
            var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
            var element4 = document.createElement("input");
            element4.type = "text";
            element4.name = "descriptextbox";
            if(textbox1.value==''){element4.value="-";}
            else
            element4.value=textbox1.value;
            cell4.appendChild(element4);
            //cell4.contenteditable=true;
           /* var addRowBox = document.createElement("input");
            addRowBox.setAttribute("type", "button");
            addRowBox.setAttribute("value", "Edit");



            var cell5 = row.insertCell(5);
            cell5.appendChild(addRowBox);*/


            var deleteRowBox = document.createElement("input");
            deleteRowBox.setAttribute("type", "button");
            deleteRowBox.setAttribute("value", "X");
            deleteRowBox.setAttribute("onclick","SomeDeleteRowFunction(this)");

            var cell6 = row.insertCell(4);
            cell6.appendChild(deleteRowBox);
            }}





    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store data and then load from localStorage if you want it to persist after page refresh.

Comment: ya thats true but since this is a dynamic table, I think the localStorage will not be feasible to use

Answer (score 0):

To keep your data upon page refresh you need to save it somewhere, for future (after page reload) access.

- Store it somewhere at your backend, and then access your, for instance, REST service upon page load.
- Store it in localStorage\sessionStorage in browser.

There are no other ways to keep data without actually keeping it :)